# difference between request.ip and request.headers['x-forwarded-for']

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get ip of the client. I run my node app(express) with this:

```
 var ip = request.ip
```

Also I saw that it's possible to do like that(which doesn't work when I run my script on localhost):

```
 var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for']
```

What the (result) difference between them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: @SLaks thank you. So is that mean: req.ip - gives me "last" (immediate) ip, but req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] gives me sequence of all the proxies + client ip ?

Comment: Express just does something like `X-Forwarded-Proto'.split(/\s*,\s*/)[0]` where it splits the ips up and gets the first one from the header, so there's no real difference other than `req.ip` only returning the first ip *(the client IP)* rather than all the forwarded IP's

Comment: @adeneo thank you very much. One more question: will it be more reliable to use this piece of code to get ip:  
``` var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
       request.connection.remoteAddress || 
       request.socket.remoteAddress ||
       request.connection.socket.remoteAddress;```

Comment: Nothing is reliable, an ip adress is easily spoofed. I think in the later versions of Node, all of those pretty much do the same thing, and `req.ip` is supposed to figure it out for you, or even `req.ips` if you wanted a list of all of them etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the `'x-forwarded-for`' is set when the request pass through an HTTP proxy or load balancer. This field contains identifies the node making the request to the proxy. You can see the [IETF RFC 7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239#page-6).

> - "by" identifies the user-agent facing interface of the proxy.
> - "for" identifies the node making the request to the proxy.
> - "host" is the host request header field as received by the proxy.
> - "proto" indicates what protocol was used to make the request.

The `request.ip` is derived from the left-most entry in the X-Forwarded-For, so its the original ip address of the request. [Express doc.](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip)

Comment: Thank you. So as I understand - reliable method to get client's actual ip - doesn't exist.